# get JWT with io.jsonwebtoken

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, restful-authentication

I want to get the JWT with the library  `io.jsonwebtoken` and I would like to know if there is any similar class or method like in `OAuth2`

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());
```

or is better to user `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` in a POST method sending the username & password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RestTemplate will be OK

```
// POST Login
    // @return "Authorization string".
    private static String postLogin(String username, String password) {

        // Request Header
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        // Request Body
        MultiValueMap<String, String> parametersMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        parametersMap.add("username", username);
        parametersMap.add("password", password);

        // Request Entity
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parametersMap, headers);

        // RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // POST Login
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL_LOGIN, //
                HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();

        List<String> list = responseHeaders.get("Authorization");
        return list == null || list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0);
    }
```